# What does it exactly mean by right and left functional derivatives?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, grassmann-numbers, functional-derivatives, superalgebra

In BV formalism of the gauge theory, we need to compute the right / left functional derivatives of the actions that include fermions.

I do not quite see what it means by that.
For example, let us think of the QCD action given as
\begin{equation}
S[\psi, \overline{\psi}]:= \int d^4x \text{ } \overline{\psi} [\gamma_\mu D^\mu+m]\psi\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $\psi$ is the quark field, $\overline{\psi}$ is its Dirac adjoint, and $D^\mu$ is the covariant derivative with respect to the given gauge group (which should be $SU(3)$ but not really important here).

Then what does it mean by
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta_L S}{\delta {\psi}} \text{ or } \frac{\delta_R S}{\delta {\psi}}~?\tag{2}
\end{equation}

In the QFT book by Weinberg, it is simply stated that the derivative acts from the left or right, but I do not understand.. In particular, is it always true that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta_L S}{\delta {\psi}}=-\frac{\delta_R S}{\delta {\psi}}~?\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Could anyone please clarify?

Comment: The normal definition of derivative may not apply to non-commuting numbers, consider $f'(x)=(f(x+\epsilon)-f(x))/\epsilon$, if you interpret "divide $\epsilon$" as multiply $\epsilon^{-1}$, then for non-commuting numbers, mulitply it from left and right are different, this is the left/right derivative.

Comment: @Photon-gjq Please post your response as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: A left derivative means a derivative that acts *from* the left. A right derivative means a derivative that acts *from* the right.

In more detail, an infinitesimal variation of a functional $F[\phi]$ is of the form
$$\int \!d^4x ~ \delta \phi(x)~ \frac{\delta_L F}{\delta \phi(x)} ~=~\delta F~=~ \int \!d^4x ~~ \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \phi(x)}~ \delta \phi(x),  \tag{A}$$
where the left and right [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) satisfy
$$\frac{\delta_L F}{\delta \phi(x)}
~=~(-1)^{|\phi|(|F|+1)} \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \phi(x)}.\tag{B}$$
Here $|\cdot|$ denotes the [Grassmann-parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number).

Eq. (B) implies OP's eq. (3) for Grassmann-odd $\psi$ and Grassmann-even $S$.